# Работа с usleep

Tags: linux, c, сокет, время, can

Не могу понять почему код не отрабатывает "линейно". Точнее отрабатывает, но совсем неожиданно. Почему-то время при последующем запуске программы уменьшается в разы !!! из за чего программа работает совсем не так как мне хочется.

По сути комп при первом запуске отрабатывает программу со всеми `usleep` и `sleep`-ами. Всё шикарно.

Но следующий запуск программы отрабатывает без `usleep`-а из за чего у меня не отрабатывает алгоритм (мне для алгоритма важно чтоб *команды отправлялись через определенные интервалы времени*) и сбивается вся программа. Я думаю проблема в функции `sys_init()` (команда system), но это предположение.

Что я делаю не так ??

Вот код (функции ):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
      ...
            int b = sys_init(); // думаю тут проблема
      ...
}

 bool sys_init()
{
    system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000 "); // этот код при повторном разе не отрабатывает, но из функции "не вылетает"
    printf("ip link set %s type can bitrate %d \n", "can0", 125000);
    system("ip link set can0 up");

    // Good initialization messages road (socket)
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    const char *ifname = "can0";

    if ((s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)) < 0){
        perror("Error while opening socket");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

    addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    //    printf("%s at index %d\n", ifname, ifr.ifr_ifindex);
    if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0){
        perror("Error in socket bind");
        return 1;
    }
    // --- end initialization

    printf("start %d \n", 9);

    if(sys_init_R2DIO_80() !=1){  // было sys_init_R2DIO_8
        printf("Error sys_init_R2DIO_8 \n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(sys_init_R2DIO_90() !=1){  // было sys_init_R2DIO_9
        printf("Error sys_init_R2DIO_9 \n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(sys_init_R2AIO_30() !=1){  // было sys_init_R2AIO_3
        printf("Error sys_init_R2AIO_3 \n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(sys_init_R2AIO_10() !=1){ // было sys_init_R2AIO_1
        printf("Error sys_init_R2AIO_1 \n");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

bool sys_init_R2DIO_80()
{
    struct can_frame frame;
    int nbytes;

    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x80; frame.data[1] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(10);
    frame.data[0] = 0x81; frame.data[1] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x608;
    frame.can_dlc = 8;
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x608;
    frame.can_dlc = 8;
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x18; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2b; frame.data[1] = 0x17; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0xe8; frame.data[5] = 0x03; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2f; frame.data[1] = 0x23; frame.data[2] = 0x24; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x01; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0xfe; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x01; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x02; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x60; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x02; frame.data[2] = 0x24; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x02; frame.data[2] = 0x24; frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x07;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x20; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x62; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x10; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x01; frame.data[1] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    printf(" Initialization R2DIO 8 (real) \n " );
    return true;
}



bool sys_init_R2DIO_90(){
    struct can_frame frame;
    int nbytes;


    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x80; frame.data[1] = 0x09;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(10);
    frame.data[0] = 0x81; frame.data[1] = 0x09;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x609;
    frame.can_dlc = 8;
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x18; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2b; frame.data[1] = 0x17; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0xe8; frame.data[5] = 0x03; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2f; frame.data[1] = 0x23; frame.data[2] = 0x24; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x01; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0xfe; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x01; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x02; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x60; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x02; frame.data[2] = 0x24; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x07;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x20; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x62; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x10; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x01; frame.data[1] = 0x09;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    printf(" Initialization R2DIO 9 (real) \n " );
    return true;
}

bool sys_init_R2AIO_30()
{
    struct can_frame frame;
    int nbytes;

    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x80; frame.data[1] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(10);
    frame.data[0] = 0x81; frame.data[1] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x603;
    frame.can_dlc = 8;
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x18; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2b; frame.data[1] = 0x17; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0xe8; frame.data[5] = 0x03; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x18; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0xfe; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x01; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[1] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x11; frame.data[2] = 0x64; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x07;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x08; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x07;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x01; frame.data[1] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    printf(" Initialization R2AIO 3 (real) \n " );
    return true;
}

bool sys_init_R2AIO_10()
{
    struct can_frame frame;
    int nbytes;

    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x80; frame.data[1] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(10);
    frame.data[0] = 0x81; frame.data[1] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x601;
    frame.can_dlc = 8;
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x18; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2b; frame.data[1] = 0x17; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0xe8; frame.data[5] = 0x03; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x18; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2f; frame.data[1] = 0x23; frame.data[2] = 0x64; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x01; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0xfe; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x01; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[1] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x01; frame.data[2] = 0x64; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x07;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x01; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.data[1] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x01; frame.data[1] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x601;
    frame.can_dlc = 0;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    usleep(20);
    printf(" Initialization R2AIO 1 (real) \n " );
    return true;
}
```

---

Решил проверить а работает ли вообще `usleep`. Вот заготовка :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   usleep(300000);
   int i  = usleep(10);
   printf("%d \n", i);
   sleep(10);
   printf("Help! usleep not work\n");
   int d  = sleep(10);
   printf("sleep work :3  %d \n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Почему-то `usleep` не работает :( вообще. Но при этом `sleep` прекрастно отрабатывает, обе переменные (*d и i*) возвращает мне *0*.

Возможно ли это связано с тем что я работаю в Ubuntu ??

Comment: Сам алгоритм нерабочий. Отпаравка по сокету с задержкой 20 микросекунд не на реалтаймовой системе - это ни о чем. Ну и посмотрите, что возвращает `usleep`

Comment: Откуда взялось число в 20 микросекунд

Comment: @AntonShchyrov число в ~20 микросекунд  надо принимающему аппарату.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov обновил вопрос

Comment: Как вы определяете нерабочесть? Вы в состоянии на глаз поймать задержку в 300 миллисекунд и 10 микросекунд?

Comment: Что значит **usleep не работает???** Он возвращает (вы печатаете `i`) -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем разобрался, проблема `usleep()` недостаточное понимние его принципа работы. Как вариант заметил что и правда в СИ usleep работает неожиданно.

```
  ...
  usleep(100) // одно-поточная программа засыпает на 100 миллисекунд
  ...
```

Но увы проблему полностью не раскопал почему так происходит, особенно поразила что одноразово запускается, а при повторном увы нет :(

Решил действовать иначе, решать проблему через таймер `time.h`

**Решение "работать" через таймер.**

Подключил `#include <time.h>` и вставил функцию :

```
void delay (unsigned int msecs) {
clock_t goal = msecs*CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000 + clock();  //конвертировать msecs в счетчик часов
while ( goal > clock() );               // Цикл, пока не закончиться :3
}
```

И заменил все `usleep();` на `delay();` вот пример "обновленного" кода :

```
    bool sys_init_R2DIO_80()
{
    struct can_frame frame;
    int nbytes;

    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x80; frame.data[1] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(10);
    frame.data[0] = 0x81; frame.data[1] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x608;
    frame.can_dlc = 8;
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x608;
    frame.can_dlc = 8;
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x18; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2b; frame.data[1] = 0x17; frame.data[2] = 0x10; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0xe8; frame.data[5] = 0x03; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x2f; frame.data[1] = 0x23; frame.data[2] = 0x24; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x01; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0xfe; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x01; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x02; frame.data[2] = 0x13; frame.data[3] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x60; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x02; frame.data[2] = 0x24; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x02; frame.data[2] = 0x24; frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x07;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x20; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x02;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x03;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x04;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x05;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[3] = 0x06;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x00; frame.data[2] = 0x62; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.data[0] = 0x40; frame.data[1] = 0x10; frame.data[2] = 0x20; frame.data[3] = 0x01;
    frame.data[4] = 0x00; frame.data[5] = 0x00; frame.data[6] = 0x00; frame.data[7] = 0x00;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    frame.can_id = 0x000;
    frame.can_dlc = 2;
    frame.data[0] = 0x01; frame.data[1] = 0x08;
    nbytes = write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    delay(20);
    printf(" Initialization R2DIO 8 (real) \n " );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше объяснили в чем вообще смысл этих задержек. Скорее всего вам нужны не они, а анализ наступления какого-то события в аппаратуре (или куда там вы шлете эти байты?)

Comment: @avp по сути это инициализация аппарата. Полное событие мне не доступно в принципе, как я "не бился", не каких кодов либо исходников  я не получил.

Comment: Скорее всего сам `usleep()` не виноват (работает как ему и положено). Основываясь на том, что первый раз все включается, могу предположить, что перед повторным включением "аппарат" надо выключать. Нет ли у вас какой-то процедуры опроса текущего статуса этого аппарата? Понятно, что гаданием задачу не решить, надо документацию изучать (RTFM)